# Java - What does using the TestMode and TestConnection arguements to override a connection mean?

Tags: java, sql-server-2005, jdbc

I cannot find anything related to this assignment from my professor.  He wants us to use the TestMode and TestConnection arguments to override the connection to a database for unit testing.  Specifically, here is the transcript first and the powerpoint bullet points second.

1. You will find the lowest level we can override the connection using TestMode and TestConnection arguments.  Generally, well introduce a TestMode or TestConnection and then wrap those with functions that use the existing arguments.  For any Sequel statements we will also introduce the Testmode or TestConnection arguments as well as any functions that use Sequel, makes calls to the database, executes stored procedures, then we will introduce arguments so we can test them.  Then we are also going to create another function, a wrapper, which accepts the original arguments and then just calls the modified function, not in TestMode and a blank TestConnection.  To introduce the code but not break anything that is already there.
2. • Find the lowest level where you can override the connectioon using TestMode and TestConnection arguments or some other suitable method.

   •  Find where the connection objects are used

   •  Introduce the TestMode and TestConnection arguments to the functions

   •  Create a wrapper (wrapper) which accepts the original arguments and calls thee modified function with arguments of TestMode = false and TestConnection = “”

---

**Here is the project specs showing the TestMode and TestConnection agrs.**

All class modifications:

- Implemented changes necessary for unit testing. Added TestMode and TestConnection to existing functions which returned a Connection object
- Modified functions to use TestMode and TestConnection values
- Created wrapper with previous arguments for the modified functions. This allows the app to compile with the code changes

  ConnectionManager.java -
      Descibe any class specific modifications

Function(s) Changed:

public Connection testFunction() throws Exception

-Wrappers Created For:

public Connection getWlsConnection() throws Exception

public Connection getWlsConnection(String fileName,boolean TestMode, String TestConnection) throws Exception

public Connection getLocalConnection(String className, String url, String userId, String passwd) throws Exception

Comment: What are TestMode and TestConnection??

Comment: I am using a SQL Server 2005

Comment: Most likely those `TestMode` and `TestConnection` things are part of the software specifically written for your assignment. You need to provide more detail, and/or specify which software library you are using that contains these.

Comment: Right, I think that is correct,  He gave us the specs for the project and it was in there.  I put the specs in my original post at the bottom.